# Stopping windows changing colour scheme

Tags: windows-7, display-settings

Windows keeps saying my computer is low on memory and changing the aero scheme to basic its really annoying

I have 16gb of ram and 2 3gb 6970 gpu's i have no issues at all with anything expect from this my motherboard has a intel hd onboard gpu i think its something to do with this but all my settings are correct.

Is there anyway to tell it not to change it without asking me or to tell it how much memory is too low its driving me mad.

Comment: Installed the GPU's drivers ? Also, is windows 32bit or 64bit ?

Comment: all my drivers and everything is up to date its windows 7 home premium 64bit sorry i'm so bad at this